# Switching a number of minutes into hh:mm:ss

Tags: php

I own some custom fields containing how much minutes each related video described lasts. I just want to echo it in hours and minutes hh:mm:ss

I typed this code but it doesn't seem to work, reporting 00:00

What's wrong in it?

```
<?php 
$gmdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_duration', true); 
echo gmdate("H:i:s", strtotime($gmdate)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the builtin DateTime Class you could do it like this

```
$gmdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_duration', true); 

echo (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($gmdate*60)->format('H:i:s');
```

RESULT

```
01:16:00
```

Or remove the `:s` if you only want Hours and Minutes

```
echo (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($gmdate*60)->format('H:i');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$duration` is time in minutes, do like this:

```
$string = floor($duration/60) . ":" . ($duration % 60);
```